# ¿como obtener el id de un producto para modificar una imagen?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, bootstrap

estoy tratando de modificar una imagen en mi base de datos por el id del producto, mi tabla se llama products y mi id es id_producto, solo que al hacer el UPDATE en mi archivo upload_imagen.php no me modifica la imagen.

```html
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"])){
/* Llamar la Cadena de Conexion*/ 
include ("../config/db.php");
include ("../config/conexion.php");

$id_producto=intval($_POST['id_producto']);

$target_dir = "../imagenes/";
$carpeta=$target_dir;
if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
    mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);
}

$target_file = $carpeta . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $errors[]= "El archivo es una imagen - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        $errors[]= "El archivo no es una imagen.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $errors[]="Lo sentimos, la imagen ya existe.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 524288) {
    $errors[]= "Lo sentimos, el archivo es demasiado grande.  Tamaño máximo admitido: 0.5 MB";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    $errors[]= "Lo sentimos, sólo archivos JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF  son permitidos.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    $errors[]= "Lo sentimos, tu imagen no fue insertada.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
       $messages[]= "La imagen se ha sido insertado correctamente.";
    $ruta=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
    $update=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE products SET url_image ='$ruta' WHERE id_producto='$id_producto'"); 

    echo $id_producto;

    } else {
       $errors[]= "Lo sentimos, hubo un error subiendo la imagen.";
    }
}

if (isset($errors)){
 ?>
 <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
   <strong>Error!</strong> 
   <?php
   foreach ($errors as $error){
    echo"<p>$error</p>";
   }
   ?>
 </div>
 <?php
}

if (isset($messages)){
 ?>
 <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
   <strong>Aviso!</strong> 
   <?php
   foreach ($messages as $message){
    echo"<p>$message</p>";
   }
   ?>
 </div>
 <?php
}
}
?>
```

debajo de la sentencia UPDATE hice un echo para ver cual id del producto obtengo y me imprime que el id_producto es 0, lo que quiero saber es como obtener el id del producto que en mi tabla es 1 pero obtengo el valor 0.
muchas gracias!!

Comment: La variable $_POST['id_producto'] llega desde una petición de tipo POST generada de diferentes maneras, puede ser un form con su botón submit, una llamada ajax, etc... necesitamos esa llamada para ver dónde se asigna su valor, ¿puedes publicar tu código del form o javascript que usas? o más sencillo, quita temporalmente el intval a ver que valor tiene realmente, porque inval dice 0 cuando no es numérico.

Comment: muchas gracias!! por la ayuda!! logre solventar mi problema y la imagen  se modifica sin problema, gracias!!!!

Comment: De nada, lo ideal sería que publicaras la solución que has aplicado como respuesta.